# Are very stable super-heavy elements theoretically possible?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, elements, isotopes

I was recently reading about [superheavy elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheavy_element).

According to that article all superheavy elements currently known have only been synthesized in laboratory experiments and have a very short half-life, so they are nothing a common person could call "stable" (here I'm using the term "stable" in a rather non-technical sense, since I'm not a physicist and my background is engineering).

I was wondering whether there are theories that predict the existence of superheavy elements that can be considered "stable" in a common sense of the word, i.e. having an half-life of (say) years (at least) in a "normal" environment (i.e. not in the crust of some neutron star or the like).

BTW, I've read about [islands of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability#Other_islands_of_stability), but that deals with half-lives above expected average, not something "common people" would call "stable" by any sense of the word.

I would also like to know if the current theories, on the other hand, prohibits the existence of such superheavy elements (e.g. because there is a theoretical limit on the half-life of such elements).

Comment: The problem with such predictions is that they cover the entire range from "YES!" over "Maybe..." to "NO! NEVER, EVER, EVER!". So pick one. One of them has to be right. Is any of that "theory"? No. Theory is (will be) the final result that agrees with the best observations. As you may have seen on the Wikipedia page there are predictions for superheavy, long term stable (days, years) nuclei, but they are not backed by any observations. Even if we can make a few such nuclei in the lab, they will stay a physical curiosity. I don't see any technological uses, maybe apart from nuclear labeling.

Comment: @FlatterMann A kilonova is a more likely source of such things than a lab experiment. A kilonova should be able to make stable nuclei approaching a mass of $10^{57}$ proton masses, so the fact that nothing above 240 or so is seen in nature strongly suggests that no such long-lived nucleus exists.

Comment: @JohnDoty You got me there. Did anybody publish the hydrogen-like single-electron emission spectrum of a neutron star, yet? ;-)